# Капча после определенного ответа

Tags: php, ajax, php7

У меня есть форма входа на сайте, когда пользователь ошибается при входе в личный кабинет, например, 5 раз с вводом пароля или email, выскакивает капча, при чем запрос к базе данных отправляется с помощью ajax, то есть при определенном ответе  (когда лимит попыток исчерпан) в DOM добавляется некий div с капчей, вот тоже вставляю я div перед `class="yes"`, правильно ли это, так как скорее всего, если удалить этот класс ничего не вставится.

А как можно проверку этой капчи засунуть в php код после ее добавления? Так как, если сделать всегда обязательной проверку на капчу уже в php коде, то при ее отсутствии в DOM, будет выходить ошибка, что капча не заполнена.

Например, ниже код не пойдет:

```
 $checkcaptcha = trim($_POST['checkcaptcha']);
 if( $checkcaptcha != $_SESSION['captcha']) $errors .= '<li><strong>Неверно введен проверочный код</strong></li>';
```

Что-то вроде, если пришли постом какие-то данные, то капча есть, иначе ее нет - не пойдут, это можно все подделать.

Например код ниже, тоже не пойдет:

```
if($_POST['checkcaptcha']){
   $checkcaptcha = trim($_POST['checkcaptcha']);
   if( $checkcaptcha != $_SESSION['captcha']) $errors .= '<li><strong>Неверно введен проверочный код</strong></li>';
}
```

Не могу понять, как реализовать это программно, после ответа ajax.
Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста. Все уже основное написал, а на этом просто застрял:(

Answer (score 0):

Создайте в сессии переменную

```
incorrect-attemts
```

код примет примерно такой вид:

```
if ($_SESSION['incorrect-attempts'] <= 5) {
  // не проверяем капчу
  // если вход не удался не забываем инкрементировать переменную
} else {
  // проверяем капчу
}
```

Это очень примерный вид - вреальности стоит проверять есть ли такая переменная, не плодить дубли кода и прочее. Это исключительно идея реализации, ни в коем случае не готовое решение

Comment: Если привязывать попытки ввода пароля к сессии, то это не даст ровно ничего - скрипт взломщика будет создавать новую сессию при каждой попытке.

Comment: заведите в бд для каждого пользователя переменную incorrect-login attempts. Если она превышает 5 всегда отдавайте капчу наружу. 
И соответственно в серверном коде проверки ее также смотрите.

Comment: Дело в том, что я записываю в БД в отдельную таблицу количество попыток по ip и по введенному емайлу, даже, если такого пользователя не существует. Поэтому на каждый любой введенный ip и емайл есть 10 попыток (срок действия хранения ip и емайла в БД по истечению попыток - 1 час), далее, если в каком то из них превышает это число, выдать капчу. А все эти записи кол-ва попыток в БД происходят после того, когда уже прошла проверка на введенные данные из формы по БД, т.е. ввели логин и емайл, такого пользователя нет, попадаем в блок else. Надеюсь что-то поймете.

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. В чем проблема сначала проверить по таблице с с попытками?